# cakephp3 unitest functionality code not working

Tags: unit-testing, session, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.x

Below code in cakephp unittest users sontroller. I am using use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;

I want to see if i loggedin successfully after post. The session doesnt get set. If i predefined session then return true (commented line).assertSession gives error. How does session get set? Can i check with url onload after submit post?

```
public function testLogin()
  {
      $this->enableCsrfToken();
      $this->enableSecurityToken();

      //$this->session(
         [
            'Auth.User.id' => 2, 
            'Auth.User.username' => 'amol'
         ]
       );
      $this->post('/', [
          'username' => 'amol',
          'password' => 'abcdef'
      ]);

      $expected = [
          'id' => 2,
          'username' => 'amol'
      ];

      debug($this->post('/users/login/', [
          'username' => 'amol',
          'password' => 'testing123'
      ]));

      $this->assertSession($expected, 'Auth.User');

      $this->assertResponseCode(200);

      //if($this->debug) debug($this->_requestSession->read());

  }
```

Comment: You'll have to do some more debugging, most likely the login isn't succesful, hence the session isn't populated.

Comment: Same controller action works fine on website and takes me to dashboard with sessions set.